# Laravel 4, delete image within a post method / possible?

Tags: php, image, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am trying to delete an old user image, if the user updates his profile picture. I am using Laravel 4.1 and a resourceful UsersController.

Updating the picture works perfectly fine. A new one is saved in my folder and the file nave is overwritten in the database. However, I would like to delete the old image. Therefore I have the following code, which works fine if I use it on an empty page with route get 'test' for example

```
$oldimage = Auth::user()->profile_picture;

File::delete('img/profile_pictures/users/' . $oldimage);
```

Everytime I try to implement this into the process of updating the image, the old one is not deleted. I have already in mind that I have to delete the old one before overwriting the file name.

Does this have to do anything with the POST method the Controller uses for updating? How could I fix it?

```
public function update($id){
    $validation = Validator::make(
        Input::all(), [
            'name'=>'required', 
            'surname'=>'required', 
            'email'=>'required',
            'email' => 'email']);

    if($validation->fails()){
        return Redirect::to(
                'dashboard#profile'
            )->withInput()->withErrors(
                $validation->messages());
    }

    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->name = Input::get('name');
    $user->surname = Input::get('surname');
    $user->email = Input::get('email');

    if (Input::hasFile('profile_picture_update')) {
        $oldimage = Auth::user()->profile_picture;
        File::delete('img/profile_pictures/users/' . $oldimage);
    }

    $imageFile = Input::file('profile_picture_update');
    $newprofile_picture = Image::make(
        $imageFile->getRealPath()
    )->resize(400, null, true)->crop(400, 400);

    $name = time() . '-' . 
        Input::get('name') . 
        '-' . Input::get('surname') . 
        '.' . $imageFile->getClientOriginalExtension();

    // $name = time() . '-' . $profile_picture->getClientOriginalName();

    // Below the profile_picture variable is overrridden.
    $newprofile_picture = $newprofile_picture->save(
        public_path().'/img/profile_pictures/users/'.$name
    );
    $user->profile_picture = $name;
    $user->save();

    return Redirect::to(
        'dashboard#profile'
    )->with(
        'updatemessage', 'Yep! Deine Änderungen wurden gespeichert.'
    );
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the request method. Can you post the complete code of the Controllers method that handles the post request?

Comment: access rights would be my first guess. second: why are you actually have to delete the file. simply overwrite it.

Comment: The old file is not deleted there?

Comment: I have not implemented the code jet because it did not work. Will do now. Have a look please.

Comment: Access rights? Hm. But I can delete the file with the code I have if I put it on a blank page...???

Comment: What contains your $oldimage = Auth::user()->profile_picture; ?

Comment: You are not using public_path() when deleting the old image, maybe you want to add it. Also, you are using $user = User::find($id) AND Auth::user(), maybe there are not always the same?

Comment: The $oldimage contains the image name: test.png

Comment: The thing is that those two lines of code DO work. If I set up a simple route and paste them into the function this works fine and Laravel deletes the images. It just does not want to work in combination with creating the new one. :(

Comment: Well @chris342423 in this case they definitely have to be the same.

Comment: @chris342423 even public path does not do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this by creating a helper function an then calling the helper function in the controller method.

http://laravel.com/docs/helpers

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use the User model you just retrieved to get the old image?

```
if (Input::hasFile('profile_picture_update')) {
    $oldimage = Auth::user()->profile_picture;
    File::delete('img/profile_pictures/users/' . $oldimage);
}
```

replace it with

```
if (Input::hasFile('profile_picture_update')) {
    $oldimage = $user->profile_picture;
    File::delete('img/profile_pictures/users/' . $oldimage);
}
```

Comment: I did not have a problem with the those to lines. They simply did not work in the update function. As I sourced them out to a helper function and called this function instead everything worked out fine.